# Rmagick and carrierwave installment in dreamhost vps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, carrierwave, rmagick

I am trying to install carrierwave not on my machine but on a vps hosted on dreamhost.

Here the Gemfile

```
gem "rmagick"
gem 'carrierwave'
```

Here the error when bundling:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/wywvps/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
extconf.rb:128: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes

Warning: Found more than one ImageMagick installation. This could cause problems at runtime.
         /usr/bin/Magick-config reports version 6.6.0 Q16 is installed in /usr
         /usr/bin/X11/Magick-config reports version 6.6.0 Q16 is installed in /usr
Using 6.6.0 Q16 from /usr.

checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no

Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/wywvps/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /home/wywvps/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/wywvps/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try installing

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev imagemagick
```

Answer (score 0):

It says that you do not have "MagickWand.h" file in the wand folder.
Please check that in your installation folder of your ImageMagick is this file located.

Petr